# I am trying to understand how blockchain transaction confirmation works with irrelevant transactions

Tags: blockchain

Assume my transaction is in mining pool and it gets successfully validated.
Miner starts mining another irrelevant transactions. My transaction will be confirmed only after that miner add another one successful confirmation followed by my transaction.

Does my transaction hash is given as input to irrelevant transaction that miner is now mining?
 If not how that transaction if validated becomes confirmation for my transaction?

Comment: You may wish to ask instead on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You asking incorrect question. Miner mines a `block`, not a `transaction`. Block includes some transaction set, but transaction within that set can be completely independent. Or can be dependent - when one transaction spends output of another transaction.

Thus, a `blocks` (not transactions) organized into the blockahain, and each block depends on previous. But, transactions can has, or can do not has dependencies.

> Does my transaction hash is given as input

Your transaction hash is participate as input of the [Merkle Tree](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) of transaction set, and root of that tree is included into block header.